# How can I split the django-haystack search form and the results

Tags: django-haystack

I want to have the search form of django-haystack on the base.html template of my blog but the results on a different template page how can I do that ?

Answer (score 10):

Structure the form to submit the data to the correct URL,

```
      <form action="/search/?q=">
        <input type="text" name="q" id="id_q">
        <button type="submit">Go</button>
      </form>
```

So that code would live on the base.html page, and than submissions to it would post to the default '/search' page, the full search bar/options and results. I have this code in use on a pinax site with the default haystack install and it works.

Comment: why `<form action= "/search/?q="` can't we use `<form method="get" action="/search/" `